# why does the input in the array overwrites the values of each row

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

i have this piece of code

```
x=3
a=x*[x*[0]]
for i in range(0,x):
   for j in range(0,x):
       dt=int(input("insert data: "))
       a[i][j]=dt
       print(a)
```

and it's supposed to just add the numbers when is asked, but for some reason it fills the numbers in all the rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just created 3 rows with the same reference with `a=x*[x*[0]]`. `x*[0]` is built once, and propagated on all rows by the outer multiply operator.

Changing a row changes *all* the rows. Note that it can be useful (but not there obviously)

Do that instead (using a list comprehension):

```
a=[x*[0] for _ in range(x)]
```

so references of each row are separated

Comment: The joys of python object referencing.

Comment: I must admit I got caught too some time ago :)

Comment: yup - Apparently, it still gets me today ;)